# Maintaining order with Stylelint v15.11.0

Tags: javascript, stylelint

My team's React project has been configured as follows wrt `stylelint` :

```
"stylelint": "^13.12.0",
"stylelint-config-prettier": "^8.0.2",
"stylelint-config-recommended": "^4.0.0",
"stylelint-config-sass-guidelines": "^7.1.0"
```

In `.stylelintrc.json` are these key parts:

```
"extends": [
  "stylelint-config-recommended",
  "stylelint-config-sass-guidelines",
  "stylelint-config-prettier"
],
"rules": {
  "order/order": null,
  "order/properties-alphabetical-order": null,
```

A message appeared that suggested we should upgrade to `v15.11.0`.  I did so.  I then uninstalled `stylelint-config-recommended` and `stylelint-config-prettier` because they were deprecated with this newer version of `stylelint`.

But then those 2 rules shown above appeared with errors about them being "Unknown rules".

We absolutely do want to maintain the order that Stylelint has enforced.  I'm not sure what to do to fix this.  Any ideas?

Robert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [order rule](https://github.com/hudochenkov/stylelint-order/blob/HEAD/rules/order/README.md) of the [stylelint-order plugin](https://github.com/hudochenkov/stylelint-order).

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "stylelint-order"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "order/order": [
            "custom-properties",
            "declarations"
        ],
        "order/properties-order": [
            "width",
            "height"
        ]
    }
}
```